# DllImport and EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

in my appllication i have to laod the dll dynamically.I have loaded a dll dynamically using the DllImport attribute. But I got the following exception.

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException
```

Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named "Connect_Net" in DLL zkemkeeper.dll'.

What would be the possible reasons for this exception. How can I handle this. Please help me.

Here is my Code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\zkemkeeper.dll", EntryPoint = "Connect_Net")]
    public static extern bool Connect_Net(string IPAdd, int Port);

    [DllImport("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\zkemkeeper.dll", EntryPoint = "Disconnect")]
    public static extern void Disconnect();




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var res = Connect_Net("192.168.1.201", Convert.ToInt32(4370));

        Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code. But surely your entry-point is wrong declared so the "windows dll-entry-standard" simply cannot find it.

Comment: Run dumpbin.exe /exports on that DLL so you **know** what the entrypoint function names are.  You'll probably see just 4 functions, like DllGetClassObject().  Which means that you should add a reference to the DLL so you can use the COM component directly.

Comment: After running dumpbin.exe /exports on my DLL only 5 functions listed. I can't see my required function. I have to load the dll dynamically, so is there any way to access the required function dynamically.

Comment: @HansPassant if a function is not listed after running dumpbin.exe /exports on a DLL, is there any way to access that function without refering that dll.

Comment: I predicted you would not see it.  I can merely guess what you did see.  There's very little point in making this a guessing game.

Answer (score 2):

There is just a single explanation for this error. Namely that the DLL in question does not export a function named `Connect_Net`. Some possible reasons for this are:

- The function is simply not exported by the DLL.
- You have mis-typed the function name. Note that exported function names are case sensitive.
- The function is exported but has a decorated or mangled name.

Use `dumpbin.exe /exports` to list the functions exported by the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this ( If You have the correct definitions of the dll specs ).

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(@"Your.dll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int GetWhatever(string vone, string vtwo, string vthree);
```

Comment: What is Your exception ?

Comment: I got the same exception.

Comment: Where are the documents of Your mentioned dll ? Do You have any ? Did You write the dll or who did that ? sanmple.dll is not the same as zkemkeeper.dll, something is mixed up there.

Comment: @icbytes Can you explain what point your answer is making. In what way does your p/invoke solve the problem?

Comment: My answer is, what usually works for me, therefore I hoped, it would help the op , too.